# List of Spotify song urls/numbers?

Tags: database, csv, spotify, plaintext

I am working on a music game website and I am using the Spotify play button. This takes spotify track numbers/urls and I am looking for a huge list of them with which to populate my database. Does anyone know where I could find such a list? Or do I have to write a script to try and scrape them?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many millions of tracks in Spotify so that'd be a pretty unmanageable list.

More importantly, scraping the Spotify catalog like this is very much against Spotify's API Terms of Service, and if you try it you'll find yourself rate limited pretty fast.

Instead, consider asking users of their game to search for something - searching for a user-supplied string and caching the results of the search doesn't break the Terms of Service.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I could have them upload their urls for their library (anonymously) which would help populate my database.